# Extra space in first value of CSV when reading with PHP

Tags: php, csv, multidimensional-array

```
<?php
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('Testcsv.csv'));
print_r($csv);
```

This code parses the Testcsv.csv file that looks like this..

```
4,5,6,7,8
9,10,11,12,13
0,1,3,2,15
```

However the last print statement returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 7
            [4] => 8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 11
            [3] => 12
            [4] => 13
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 15
        )

)
```

vardump($csv) produces

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>
  array(5) {
        [0]=>
    string(4) " 4"
        [1]=>
    string(1) "5"
        [2]=>
    string(1) "6"
        [3]=>
    string(1) "7"
        [4]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
        [0]=>
    string(1) "9"
        [1]=>
    string(2) "10"
        [2]=>
    string(2) "11"
        [3]=>
    string(2) "12"
        [4]=>
    string(2) "13"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
        [0]=>
    string(1) "0"
        [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
        [2]=>
    string(1) "3"
        [3]=>
    string(1) "2"
        [4]=>
    string(2) "15"
  }
}
```

No matter what I do or how I format the csv, the first value always gets an empty space pushed in front of it. In this case, " 4" instead of "4". I can't understand why. I am on a mac computer, and without the first line of code things get really wonky as it doesn't detect the line breaks. I created and saved the .csv in Excel. Any insight helps, thanks.

Comment: Are you using notepad or excel to open the open/modify the file? Also what does `var_dump($csv)` produce?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your file actually has that character, or a hidden character in front of it.

To find out what it, open your terminal. If the file is called 'foo.csv', use:

```
hexdump -C foo.csv
```

This will give you a hexdump of your file. I'm almost certain that you find a hidden character before the first 4.

**edit** thanks for posting the hexdump. Your file contains a UTF-8 BOM. Either make sure that whatever creates the file does not output the UTF-8 BOM, or clean up the file before you open it.

Writing a UTF-8 BOM is mostly no longer done by modern software. I don't think it's recommended anymore but some software might still do this.

Comment: if i do that i get
`00000000  ef bb bf 34 2c 35 2c 36  2c 37 2c 38 0d 39 2c 31  |...4,5,6,7,8.9,1|

00000010  30 2c 31 31 2c 31 32 2c  31 33 0d 30 2c 31 2c 33  |0,11,12,13.0,1,3|

00000020  2c 32 2c 31 35                                    |,2,15|

00000025`

Comment: is there a way I can remove this using php?